# Stuck using the multipleGroup and DIF functions in mirt package

Tags: r, validation, statistics, factor-analysis

Feeling stuck on this one and would love some advice. I think I'm getting lost on terms which is what's holding me back. In my code (below), I'm trying to run two DIF analyses, one on race and one on gender. I believe what I'm reading in the documentation is that in order to use the DIF function, I have to pass at least a model from the multipleGroups function and a grouping variable (i.e. race or gender). Right now I'm getting hung up because when I try to run the code below, I'm getting the following error: Error: group input provided is not valid. I thought what I was passing was an array of the grouping variable "race" or "gender" but I guess I'm not, given the error. Any help on how to fix that error and/or set up the grouping variable in the DIF function once I have the multipleGroup error cleared up would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Andrew

````
#re-load a clean data set 
Q_Data <- read_excel("C:/Data/Data_Spring_2021.xlsx")
#create a gender grouping variable
gender <- Q_Data$Demo_Sex


#create a race grouping variable

race <- Q_Data$Demo_Race

#define the model

fullModel <- 'f1 = Q_1, Q_2, Q_3, Q_4, Q_5, 
Q_6, Q_7, Q_8, Q_9, Q_10, Q_11, Q_12, 
Q_13, Q_14, Q_15, Q_16, Q_17, Q_18'

gmModel <- 'f1 = Q_4, Q_5, Q_8, Q_9, Q_14, Q_16'

cuModel <- 'f1 = Q_3, Q_6, Q_10, Q_15, Q_17, Q_18'

diModel <- 'f1 = Q_1, Q_2, Q_7, Q_11, Q_12, Q_13'

#set the model for use in mirt
fullModel <- mirt.model(fullModel)

F1Model <- mirt.model(F1Model)
cuModel <- mirt.model(cuModel)
diModel <- mirt.model(diModel)

#run multipleGroups on total score
Full_Race <- multipleGroup(Q_Data, fullModel, race)
Full_Gender <- multipleGroup(Q_Data, fullModel, gender)

#run multipleGroups on factor scores

F1_Race <- multipleGroup(Q_Data, F1Model, race)
F1_Gender <- multipleGroup(Q_Data, F1Model, gender)

F2_Race <- multipleGroup(Q_Data, F2Model, race)
F2_Gender <- multipleGroup(Q_Data, F2Model, gender)

F3_Race <- multipleGroup(Q_Data, F3Model, race)
F3_Gender <- multipleGroup(Q_Data, F3Model, gender)


#Look at DIF

DIF(Full_Race, which.par = race)```
````

Answer (score 0):

What I got from Phil Chalmers, developer of the mirt package:

The `which.par` input to `DIF()` is looking for which type of parameters to test in the respective items (e.g., do you want to test the intercept parameters only? `which.par = 'd'`. Non-uniform DIF via freeing the slope-intercept terms for df=2 test? `which.par = c('a1', 'd')))`. There's a number of examples in the help file that you might find useful to inspect prior to executing your own analyses. Alternatively, you can always investigate DIF by comparing multiple-group models with whatever constraints you prefer in the nested MG models.

Answer (score 0):

Check the values in your Group array. Try to convert to character if not, like using dplyr package:

```
group <- dplyr::recode(group, "1"="Race1", "2"="Race2")
```